# How can I insert values into a multi-layer Dictionary in C#?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have to write a Dictionary which will be

```
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>>() { };
```

so later i'll just check and get values like

```
if (dictionary[index].key* == value) { stuff; }    //*or maybe it's [index][key], that's not the matter
```

I just don't know and understand how to write the various elements inside the dictionary (i already searched here and online), the proper syntax, anything i try gets an error. Hope you can help, thank you in advance!

Comment: `dictionary[newIndex] = new Dictionary<string, string>();` Is that your question?

Comment: i don't understand newIndex. it will have an undefined number of int as exterior key (need it later, as Index to query according to a comboBox index), so after getting directly the proper Index i'll get inside the proper string Key and check if the string Value fits to my need.

Comment: newIndex is an arbitrary name for a new index of the main dictionary (your combobox index)

Comment: What elements are you going to put into the dictionary?

Comment: ok...no, well, as i said, my problem is how to create a multiple layer dictionary to store data/values with proper indexes/keys. i already did it (kind of) with a resource file .txt, but this time i just need to write it in the code (and the txt file syntax doesn't seem to work, which was like { Indexofelement: { key1: stuff, key2: stuff} }

Comment: Do you know how to write stuff in regular dictionary?

Comment: all solved, but i didn't use multiple layers before, i just used single paired keys:values, this is different and i didn't know why it was wrong and how i should do it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name `index` isn't really appropriate, because dictionaries don't use indices they use keys.

However, to add a new sub-dictionary:

```
dictionary[i] = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

To add / replace a value in an existing sub-dictionary:

```
dictionary[i][key] = value;
```

If you want to safely insert a new value when a sub-dictionary may or may not have been created, you could create an extension method:

```
public static void Insert(this Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>> dict, int i, string key, string value)
{
    if (!dict.ContainsKey(i)) dict[i] = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    dict[i][key] = value;
}
```

Then use like this:

```
dictionary.Insert(1, "SomeKey", "SomeValue");
```

Just note that this will overwrite keys in the sub-dictionary if the same key is inserted more than once.

Answer (score 0):

To insert into this object:

```cs
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>>() { };
```

You'll need to do multiple inserts. So something like:

```cs
//create the first level and instanciate a new dictionary object
dictionary.Add(1234, new Dictionary<string, string>());
//insert into the dictionary created above
dictionary[1234].Add("test", "test");
```

`dictionary[1234]` here returns a `Dictionary<string, string>` where `1234` is the key added in `dictionary.Add(1234, new Dictionary<string, string>());`

Answer (score 0):

How about using [collection initialisers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers)? This is great if you have constant values that you want the dictionary to contain:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>>() { 
    [111] = new Dictionary<string, string> {
        ["nested key1"] = "value 1",
        ["nested key2"] = "value 2",
        ["nested key3"] = "value 3",
        ["nested key4"] = "value 4",
    },
    [222] = new Dictionary<string, string> {
        ["nested key5"] = "value 5",
        ["nested key6"] = "value 6",
        ["nested key7"] = "value 7",
        ["nested key8"] = "value 8",
    },
};
```

Answer (score -1):

`dictionary` has type `Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>>`, so `var b = dictionary[3]` has type `Dictionary<string, string>`, and to get an entry of `b` use syntax `b["Hello"]` to get a `string`. 
If you want to write them in one clause, use `(dictionary[3])["Hello"]`. Since `operator[]` is left-associative, `(dictionary[3])["Hello"]` can be written as `dictionary[3]["Hello"]`.

Comment: you didn't understand. i know how to call values, i don't know how to insert them in the dictionary.